# Bold italic text not given correct color on mobile

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, mobile-web, rendering

[image: Screenshot]

You see I can tap on the link and it behaves totally well. Yet its color shouldn't be black, though.

MD source:

```
[***Link***][1] blah text.

  [1]: /.
```

Demo:

[***Link***](/.) blah text.

Comment: @AndrewT At least MSE and SO.

Comment: Confirmed here on MSE. For some reason, the mobile style sheet has the rule `em { color: #0C0D0E }`, making all italic text (almost) black. There's another rule (`a, a>em { color: #D58E10 }`) that overrides it for italics (directly) inside links, but it fails to match your example, since the HTML there looks like `<a href="/."><strong><em>Link</em></strong></a>`. I'd be inclined to suggest just getting rid of the first rule entirely, unless somebody can figure out a halfway sensible reason for having it in the first place.